# Reading values from a file into a non corresponding array

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing code in c. The method I currently use to read values from a file into an array is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  int a,b;
  double array[3][3];

   FILE *file;
   char *myfile=malloc(sizeof(char)*80);
   sprintf(myfile,"example.txt");

       if (fopen(myfile,"r")==NULL)
       {
       }

       else
       {
        file=fopen(myfile,"r");
         for (a=0;a<3;a++)
         {
           for (b=0;b<3;b++)
           {
              fscanf(file,"%lf",&array[a][b]);
           }
         }fclose(file);
       }
}
```

If I have a file with values

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

this code will read in each value one at a time into the array. This works for most of my purposes. However, I want to either write a new code or modify this to read in only certain values. For example, I would only want to read in the numbers `3 6 9` from the file into `array[3][1]` where the the first row would be 3, the second row would be 6, and the third row would be 9. I don't know how to do that and I have not been able to find a solution so far.

Comment: Read all values and discard those that you are not interested in?  You need not read directly into the array.  Read into a temporary variable and copy it into the array as you see fit.

Comment: How could I go about reading into a temporary variable?

Comment: `double temp; fscanf(file,"%lf",&temp); if (…) array[i][j] = temp;`

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
fscanf(file,"%lf",&array[a][b])
```

is cause for undefined behavior since you haven't initialized `file`.

Try changing the line:

```
   if (fopen(myfile,"r")==NULL)
```

to

```
   if ((file = fopen(myfile,"r")) ==NULL)
```

Also, please post compilable code. You have missing `;` in couple of lines.